# iOS bridge vs bridge_transfer

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm confused with `bridge` and `bridge_transfer`, is this correct?

```
-(void)getData{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    NSArray *allPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

    NSString *name;
    for ( int i = 0; i < [allPeople count]; i++ )
    {
        name = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)[allPeople objectAtIndex:i], kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    }
    CFRelease(addressBook);
    allPeople = nil;
}
```

Is there anyone who can explain me how to use them?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you have automatic-reference-counting (ARC) turned on, the code is correct.

There are two `__bridge_transfer` in your statements. As a result, the ownership of created CFObjects will be transferred to NSObjects. If you have ARC turned on, they will be freed up automatically. If you used `__bridge` instead for these 2 statements, you will need to explicitly call `CFRelease` to release CFObjects created by the `*Copy` API.

The `__bridge` statement is also correct. Because you are referencing an NSObject in CF API. You are not transferring ownership, so that ARC will free it up.

Comment: Ownership is an important key concept in memory management.  The "owner" of an object is responsible for releasing its memory.  If it fails to do this, the object will leak.  An object can have more than one owner though, so the last owner that goes out of scope is responsible for deallocation in this case.  ARC does this automatically, but ONLY for objective-C objects.  CoreFoundation objects are vanilla C objects so you need to give the compiler hints about how to deal with them.  If you "transfer ownership" to ARC, you say that it is ARC's responsibility to deallocate the object.

Comment: Sorry for lateness in response. Ownership is mainly about who's responsible for free up the object. If you want the details, please refer to [Ownership Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html).

Answer (score 19):

It is very very simple, When you use ARC (automatic reference counting) the compiler will take care of counting how many objects are being pointed by your variables. When the count goes to 0 the object is automatically dealocated. SO for things that come from a low level structure, like core foundation, the compiler doesnt know what to do. So you use BRIDGE if you just want to tell the compiler "ignore this one, i will release it when i need it". or Bridge transfer if you want to say "Treat this as an object and release it when the reference goes to 0).

When you do this, you create a copy that under normal circumstances should be released by a "CFRelease":

```
ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook)
```

However by adding this, you are **transferring** the ownership to an objective-c object:

```
NSArray *allPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)........
```

So the NSArray will be managed by ARC.

---

Note that as JRG mentions, doing this:

```
CFRelease(addressBook);
```

Does not affect the newly created object in anyway, but instead the original one which you still have to manually release: (It's easy to tell because those methods usually have the **create** or **copy** keywords in their names)

---

Something that does not happen in your code but you should be careful with is that releasing core foundation objects which are NULL with CFRelease will cause an error. As Paul mentions in his comment.

Comment: Unlike `[nil release]` which is fine, `CFRelease(NULL)` causes an error.

Comment: yes you are right, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTypeRef/Reference/reference.html "If cf is NULL, this will cause a runtime error and your application will crash."

Comment: -1: `NSArray *allPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);` transfers ownership of the array that's returned. This doesn't have anything to do with  `addressBook`. Rather, `addressBook` must be released because it was created with a "create" method (`ABAddressBookCreate`). Otherwise, it will leak.

Comment: @JRG-Developer yeah you are correct, thanks for pointing it out. I don't know what I was thinking back then. Fixed the answer anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Luis Oscar I'm still working out my understanding of ARC, but I believe addressBook does need CFRelease. ARC is not managing addressBook. NSArray *allPeople is being managed by ARC via the __bridge_transfer cast hint and it is being created as a copy of the original. Without the CFRelease, addressBook will leak.

Answer (score 0):

One edit: I believe calling CFRelease on a nil object does cause the app to crash