# Huge memory footprint with ARC

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

App I'm working on uses ARC. I wanted it to process large files, so instead of loading files as a whole, I'm loading chunks of data using NSFileHandle readDataOfLength method. It's happening inside a loop which repeats until the whole file is processed:

```
- (NSString*)doStuff { // called with NSInvocationOperation

    // now we open the file itself

    NSFileHandle *fileHandle =
    [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingFromURL:self.path
                                        error:nil];

    ...

    BOOL done = NO;
    while(!done) {

        NSData *fileData = [fileHandle readDataOfLength: CHUNK_SIZE];

        ...

        if ( [fileData length] == 0 ) done = YES;

        ...

    }

    ...

}
```

According to profiler, there are no memory leaks; however, my app eats a LOT of memory while it processes the file. My guess — autorelease comes only after I process the file. Can I fix it without switching to manual memory management?

Comment: Please post the code pertaining to your problem

Comment: @mdvs it's not easily googleable; can you please provide a link to what you're talking about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap the code within that loop with a autorelease pool.

```
while(!done) 
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSData *fileData = [fileHandle readDataOfLength: CHUNK_SIZE];
        ...
        if ( [fileData length] == 0 ) 
        {
            done = YES;
        }
        ...                
    }
};
```

`readDataOfLength` retuns autoreleased data and since you stick inside that loop and therefor its method, that autoreleased data that does not get released until your loop and the encapsulating method is done.

Comment: If my suggested method does not work for you (for reasons that I am unaware of as tagging specific implementation files to be excluded from ARC is a standard feature), consider using a different method of reading the data - e.g. CoreFoundations `CFReadStreamRead`.

Comment: "tagging specific implementation files to be excluded from ARC is a standard feature" well, it seems that my answer is right there. I actually didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: Also have a look at this: http://www.joel.lopes-da-silva.com/2010/09/07/compute-md5-or-sha-hash-of-large-file-efficiently-on-ios-and-mac-os-x/

Comment: @golergka Huh? `@autoreleasepool{}` is explicitly intended for use with ARC: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @ConradShultz I initially used the old way of declaring that pool - that is what golergka might have commented on.

Comment: @Till Ah, that makes more sense.  Late to the party I guess. :-)

Comment: @ConradShultz actually, I didn't know that either.

Comment: Aye :D ... I have now suggested three options. Old way; exclude from ARC and use old way of declaring the pool. New way; use @autoreleaspool. Hard way; use CoreFoundation without autoreleasing.

Comment: When using CoreFoundation objects and ARC, you can use `__bridge_transfer` to transfer ownership of the objects to ARC, where they are then released automatically, or you can use `__bridge` and manually call `CFRelease`. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859639/ios-bridge-vs-bridge-transfer